# How to copy a file to another directory using ssh?

Tags: ssh

How would I copy somefile.zip to another directory?

Answer (score 7):

If you are connected to a shell session via ssh, and the file exists on the remote system, you can use the cp command.

```
cp sourcefile destfile
```

If the file exists on the local system you should use sftp. If your local machine runs Windows, [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) is an excellent sftp client.

Comment: why would you use sftp when you have scp, which goes over SSH so it doesn't require any extra software or ports?

Comment: The original poster didn't say they had `scp`. Assuming they don't have it, WinSCP is much easier. Furthemore, sftp uses the same port as ssh.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using the command line then like this

`scp myfile.txt dest/`

for a local file or alternatively

`scp user@myserver:/path/to/myfile.txt user@myserver:/path/to/dest/`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Win32, Tunnellier is a reasonable solution which not only allows file transfer, but secure remote access as well.